# What is the recommended way to create an ExchangeRateProvider in JavaMoney (JSR 354)?

Tags: java, java-money, jsr354

We have started using the new 1.0 version of [JavaMoney API](https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-api) with the [reference implementation](https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-ri). Since we have specific Exchangerates that should be used, we need to implement our own [ExchangeRateProvider](http://mavenbrowse.pauldoo.com/central/javax/money/money-api/1.0/money-api-1.0-javadoc.jar/-/javax/money/convert/ExchangeRateProvider.html). We have created a class MyRateProvider that extends [org.javamoney.moneta.spi.AbstractRateProvider](http://mavenbrowse.pauldoo.com/central/org/javamoney/moneta/1.0/moneta-1.0-javadoc.jar/-/org/javamoney/moneta/spi/AbstractRateProvider.html) and added MyRateProvider-name to the file META-INF/services/javax.money.convert.ExchangeRateProvider. It works, but all the other providers in org.javamoney.moneta are also loaded even if we are not going to use them. Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

We have an issue today, currently we're looking for modules on moneta.
That we did on this PR: https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-ri/pull/135

That will be fixed on 1.2 version.